# Swift UIAlertController causing Autolayout Engine warning

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

For some reason, once I presented and dismissed a UIAlertController my subsequent navigations will cause a lot of Autolayout Engine warnings, like this:

> 2016-02-11 12:22:33.389 MyAppName [19989:13348136] This application is
>   modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can
>   lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an
>   exception in a future release.  Stack:(   0   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010a708f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x000000010c654deb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010a708e7d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205     3   Foundation 
>   0x000000010aea2289 _AssertAutolayoutOnMainThreadOnly + 79     4
>   Foundation                          0x000000010ad024e2 -[NSISEngine
>   optimize] + 49    5   Foundation
>   0x000000010ad02da4 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] +
>   245   6   UIKit                               0x000000010b1f0d4a
>   -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 575   7   UIKit                               0x000000010b1eed53 __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 213    8   UIKit
>   0x000000010b1ee905 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 422     9
>   MyAppName                           0x000000010a48586b
>   _TFFC10PeterPiper18AutoFetchImageView19setRelativeFilePathFS0_FTGSqSS_10completionGSqFT_T___T_U_FTGSqCSo7UIImage_GSqCSo7NSError_GSqSb__T_
>   + 395

My code is like

```
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I searched around and tried put the code in dispatch_async block on the main thread as suggested by so many different discussions on stack overflow but I still get the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where exactly are you calling this code ?

Comment: Inside my root level view and in other places too.

Comment: are these warnigs appeared after you present/dismiis the alert ?

Comment: After I dismissed the alert, these warnings started to appear with my subsequent navigation movements.